# C: Undefined reference to function using header

Tags: c, header-files

I see that this question has been answered however I still can't resolve this.

I have 3 files `main.c`, `basicMath.c`, and `basicMath.h`. I have declared a function `addition()` in `basicMath.h` and have `#include "basicMath.h"` in main and have defined the function in `basicMath.c`. However, when building I keep getting an `undefined reference to "addition"` error even when I clearly declared and defined it. My course graced over this topic and wants me to code like this. Doing my own research leads to the same thing. I do exactly what I read/ watch and I still get an error. Any insight? My code is below and using Code Blocks as my IDE.

`Main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "basicMath.h"

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 7;

    printf("%d", addition(a, b));

    return 0;
}
```

`basicMath.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "basicMath.h"

int addition(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

`basicMath.h`

```
#ifndef BASICMATH_H_INCLUDED
#define BASICMATH_H_INCLUDED

int addition(int a, int b);

#endif // BASICMATH_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: When you created new file basicMath.c in project, did you check checkboxes "debug" and "release" under checked checkbox "Add file to active project in build target(s)" ?

Comment: How did you make sure that the file with the definition is compiled and linked, i.e. actualyl built into the executable? Did you verify that it is at least compiled? The easiest way to do that is to write `#error This is actually compiled` in the first line of the file in question. If you do not see that error during building then it is not.

Comment: @NikolayFomichev First time I didn't. I recreated the files and checked them and it now complies successfully. Thank you.